# Laravel and Livewire change button style on click

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css, laravel-livewire

I have two buttons in tailwindcss in my

```
<div class="flex flex-row">

<button class="-ml-px relative inline-flex items-center space-x-2 px-4 py-4 border border-blue-300 text-sm font-medium rounded-l-md text-white bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-600 focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-blue-500">
<span>Add</span>
</button>

<button class="-ml-px relative inline-flex items-center space-x-2 px-4 py-4 border border-gray-300 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 bg-gray-50 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-blue-500">
<span>Set</span>
</button>

</div>
```

one button is blue and other is grey.
I want to switch colour when I click on Set Button and also same when I click back to Add button again.

Comment: The idea of Livewire is to manage interaction with backend code, not to modify classes on frontend actions. I suggest using AlpineJS for things like this, you can easily do it with that in a clean way.

Comment: Thanks and could you please help how, I am new and struggling

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve. Can you elaborate on which effect you are trying to achieve, and when? Which colors should switch on which click, and from which color to which color?

Comment: I just want to switch blue colour, like any button I click become blue and other grey.. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned, Livewire is for interaction with backend code. If you want to style frontend elements following frontend interaction, use a JS Framework like AlpineJS or plain CSS.

If you really just want to change focus color, you can go with a variation of @Digvijay's answer:

```html
<div class="flex space-x-4">
  <button class="flex px-4 py-2 bg-gray-100 text-gray-900 cursor-pointer hover:bg-blue-200 focus:text-blue-700 focus:bg-blue-200 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-600" tabindex="1">Add</button>
  <button class="flex px-4 py-2 bg-gray-100 text-gray-900 cursor-pointer hover:bg-blue-200 focus:text-blue-700 focus:bg-blue-200 focus:outline-none focus:ring-gray-600" tabindex="2">Set</button>
</div>
```

(see https://play.tailwindcss.com/mwspfpsTuU)

If you want the colors to stick even after the focus is lost, you may use something like this with AlpineJS:

```html
<div x-data="{ highlightedButton: '' }" class="flex space-x-4">
  <button @click="highlightedButton='add'" class="flex px-4 py-2 bg-gray-100 text-gray-900 hover:bg-blue-200" :class="{'bg-blue-400': highlightedButton === 'add'}" tabindex="1">Add</button>
  <button @click="highlightedButton='set'" class="flex px-4 py-2 bg-gray-100 text-gray-900 hover:bg-blue-200" :class="{'bg-blue-400': highlightedButton === 'set'}" tabindex="2">Set</button>
</div>
```

And finally if you keep track of the Add / Set state in the Livewire component anyways (which is hard to tell because there is no livewire code in your markup at all), then do it like @AliAli described in his answer. :-)

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:**
If anyone came to this answer, this is a solution when storing the button state is needed, in other cases, you should follow @Lupinity Labs answer.

You can use Livewire event listeners to change the frontend.

First, declare variables inside the Livewire PHP model like:

```
public $isSetClicked = false;
public $isAddClicked = false;
```

Then decalre functions to handle the onClick event:

```
public function SetClicked()
    {
     //this will give you toggling behavior
     $this->isSetClicked == false ? $this->isSetClicked = true : $this->isSetClicked = false;
}
```

and declare the AddClicked the same way.

Then inside your Livewire template add the events to the buttons like:

```
<button wire:click="SetClicked()" class="{{$isSetClicked  ? "color-class" : "other-color-class"}} the rest of your css classes">
```

Comment: While this is a possible solution, implementing a state for each button and a method to toggle those in the backend just for display reasons seems to be a really bad practice. If on the other hand the state needs to be kept by the Livewire component anyways, I would agree to do it like this.

Comment: @LupinityLabs Yes, I totally agree with you and I don't recommend my answer if there's a lot of frontend changes, this is absolutely where we need Javascript like AlpineJS.

Comment: Of course this is not recommendable, but why just want to change the color of a button? There must be another interaction, so for that this solution is perfect.
Thank you Ali

Comment: dont use server side for this kind of problems, better hhandle withh alpine

Answer (score 1):

To toggle HTML attributes with livewire, for example **class, id, href** and so on you have to work with [AlpineJS](https://alpinejs.dev/) inside livewire ([docs](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/alpine-js)). For example you want to change some element CSS **class attribute** by changing a some internal state (model) inside your livewire component. For example by clicking a some link.

**/app/Http/Livewire/YourLivewireComponent.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Livewire;
use Livewire\Component;

class YourLivewireComponent extends Component
{
    public $classChanged = false;

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.your-liveweire-component');
    }

    public function myClickFunction()
    {
        $this->classChanged = true;
    }
}
```

**/resources/views/livewire/your-livewire-component.blade.php**

```
<a href="#" wire:click="myClickFunction">Click me</a>
<div x-data="{ alpine_class_changed: @entangle('classChanged') }" class="some classes" x-bind:class="alpine_class_changed ? 'my_add_class' : ''">some text</div>
```

**/resources/views/somelaraveltemplate.blade.php**

```
<p>some HTML code</p>
@livewire('your-liveweire-component')
```

Comment: dont use server side for this kind of problems, better hhandle withh alpine

Answer (score -1):

You will need to use **tabindex**. Checkout [focus change on button](https://play.tailwindcss.com/2XEApJs3XR) working example.

```
<div class="flex space-x-4">
  <div class="flex px-4 py-2 bg-blue-600 text-blue-100 cursor-pointer hover:bg-blue-700 focus:text-blue-700 focus:bg-blue-200 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-600" tabindex="1">Add</div>
  <div class="flex px-4 py-2 bg-gray-100 text-gray-600 cursor-pointer hover:bg-gray-200 focus:text-gray-100 focus:bg-gray-600 focus:outline-none focus:ring-gray-600" tabindex="1">Set</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How does this answer relate to the question? Also, using the same tabindex on two different elements does not seem helpful either. Also, why did you turn his buttons into divs? I'm confused.